# HTML / CSS - link not taking width and height of parent div even though they are set to 100%

Tags: html, css, href

This is my html:

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="logoContainer">
        <a id='logoClick' href='/'></a>
        <p id="welcome">Welcome</p>
        <h1 class="logoText">first<img id="logoImage" src="image.jpeg" /><span id="second">second</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#logoClick {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#loginHeader {
    font-family: consola;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}


#logoContainer {
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Form some reason, the link is taking up the width and height of the entire page and has a padding of 20px on the top-left and top.. Any idea why?

Comment: i dont understand the title matched with your description. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The link is positioned absolutely which removes it from the normal flow and positions itself relative to the next positioned element. The parent of the anchor is not a positioned element.

To contain the anchor, add `position:relative;` to `#logoContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

depending on the effect you are trying to get, you can change the height/width of the link to `inherit` or you can change the position to `relative`